# Python: Create a loop of videos (clips) by using tkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am developing an app that displays advertisements. It will display in fullscreen and divide the screen into 2 parts. One part will display an image (or a slide of images). The other part will display a loop of videos, it automatically plays a list of videos in the folder and repeats them. No pause or start button is required but the sound of the video. I have tried with opencv and PIL but it just helps me to play a single video once and play without the video's sound. The code below is what I have used in my project:

```
    ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()

    if ret:
        self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame), master=self)
        self.videoCanvas.create_image(self.x, self.y, image=self.photo, anchor=CENTER)

    self.after(self.delay, self.update)
```

As I understand, it basically captures all the images in the video and displays them again in order on the canvas.

I am looking for a solution to such problem.

Comment: We're gonna need more context. What's `self.vid`? And `self.update`? What does `self` refer to? What modules did you import?

Comment: @Coal_ self is a Tk and self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source), self.update is the code above